# Java Virtual Gamepad

Tags: java, virtual, directinput, gamepad, xinput

**Problem**
I am developing a custom hardware controller and I would like to map its input to an virtual XInput controller after processecing it in Java. Essentially for all intents and purposes, I want to controll an XInput controller directly from java.

**Solutions I have thought of**

- Writing a device driver, this seems like a real pain in the ass that I would gladly avoid. I have never written a device driver before nor do I have any idea how to register an XInput controller. It seems like this will take a very long time to do, time I don't have nor want to spend.
- Using PPJoy and [this](https://github.com/dumbledore/FlypadJoystick) library. I would like to avoid this as PPJoy is very dated (over 10 years since last update I could find) and would require an additional layer to convert DirectInput to XInput. The library also refuses to compile for me.
- Develop a wrapper for [VJoy](http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net). That would however require a remap from DirectInput to XInput. I am not familiar with C/C++ wrapping but so far this seems like the best alternative.

Does anyone have a good idea how to solve this problem? I have considered skipping XInput and do it with keyboard/mouse using Robot (AWT) but games refuse to pick up the software input, most likely they only read hardware data. Emulating keyboard/mouse would be fine but not optimal as it would be rather awkward, I am not however able to find a way to do it in a way that games recognize. All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a wrapper, you won't need to know any, I repeat any C++ code, if you really don't want to. Simply use [swig](http://www.swig.org/). There are plenty of examples, start with something [basic](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html). (Note I am not going to include example because there is already enough stuff out there). If you have trouble leave a comment, and I'll help you out.

**EDIT**
Ok I'll be nice, quick example, say you have a example.h file, create a example.i in the same location with:

```
%module example

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%include "example.h"
```

Make sure swig is in your path then do:

```
%swig -java example.i
```

Then you need to build a native java library, such as how it's done [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077520/learn-java/java-tip-23--write-native-methods.html), (note you don't need to do all the javah stuff), but basically:

```
% g++ -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" 
  -shared -o example.dll example.c example.cpp
```

Which gives you your dll, which you will have to stick in your path with any other dependent libararies when running your java program. Note if you compile a 32 bit library you need to use a 32 bit jvm.

Comment: Thanks :) I will try it out later, seems I ate something bad so I am at the moment in bed and can't try it out. A wrapper around VJoy seems like the best choice. It is not that I can't read/write c++, I would just gladly avoid doing so. Making a wrapper also seems like very usuable knowledge to learn.